# setting cpu thread in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encode

I have a PC 24 Thread and when I use ffmpeg. It only uses 25% of my CPU. So, how can all of these 24 threads be used? So my CPU usage reaches 100%, because if it's 25% it's still a slow process

example:

```
ffmpeg -i video01.mkv -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay = 10: 10" output01.mkv
```

how to set 24 cpu threads?

Comment: by default it uses (IIRC) 1.5x threads as you have cores but you can force a specific number of threads with `-threads 0` ... what OS (Windows or Linux), processor and ffmpeg version (32 or 64 bit) are you using?

Comment: i using dedicated server windows 2012, spesification intel xeon 24 thread ram 104 GB

Answer (score 1):

You can set -threads 24 after the -i argument.  But you get diminishing returns once you pass from real threads into Hyperthreading type threads.  In that case, you should set -threads 12.

Answer (score 0):

It is designed so that you can still use your system for other processes. The comment explains how to manipulate ffmpeg thread behavior. If you ask me, default ffmpeg behavior is pretty good. It allows multiple encoding and decoding on same system with running separate ffmpeg processes.

If you tell me that system will do only "this" job in it's lifetime, than this PC probably an overkill for this job.

And finally, according to Amdahl's law, using too many threads may not yield linear performance speed-up either.

Hope that helps.

Comment: means there is no solution to speed up encoding?

Comment: I would try adjusting the threads parameter (as per original comment) and experiment. Do make sure you're running latest version of ffmpeg, and watch sysmon to make sure you're not getting gated on something like disk I/O.

Comment: @AmyBomer is that a NUMA system (kinda means the main board has multiple cpus installed on different sockets, probably two on your system) ?